# pyenv won't build new python version (hangs)

Tags: python, ubuntu-16.04, pyenv

I followed the [tutorial from Northwestern](https://amaral.northwestern.edu/resources/guides/pyenv-tutorial) to install pyenv and it seems the commands work. But when I run

```sh
pyenv install 3.7.0
```

(or whatever version) it just hangs. I get:

```sh
Downloading Python-3.7.0.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.0/Python-3.7.0.tar.xz
Installing Python-3.7.0...
```

I have run `tail -F /tmp/python-build.somenumber.log` and get

```sh
/tmp/python-build.numbers.number ~/Path
/tmp/python-build.numbers.number/Python-3.7.0 /tmp/python-build.numbers.number ~/path
```

until I kill the install. Then the log file has

```sh
$ tail -n 20 /tmp/python-build.numbers.log
checking for ieeefp.h... no
checking io.h usability... no
checking io.h presence... no
checking for io.h... no
checking langinfo.h usability... yes
checking langinfo.h presence... yes
checking for langinfo.h... yes
checking libintl.h usability... yes
checking libintl.h presence... yes
checking for libintl.h... yes
checking process.h usability... no
checking process.h presence... no
checking for process.h... no
checking pthread.h usability... yes
checking pthread.h presence... yes
checking for pthread.h... yes
checking sched.h usability... yes
checking sched.h presence... yes
checking for sched.h... yes
checking shadow.h usability... %
```

Testing on another build version everything looked the same the tail of the log file looks different

```sh
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for --with-pydebug... no
checking for --with-assertions... no
checking for --enable-optimizations... no
checking for --with-lto... no
checking target system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking for -llvm-profdata... no
checking for llvm-profdata... ''
checking for -Wextra... yes
checking whether gcc accepts and needs -fno-strict-aliasing... no
checking if we can turn off gcc unused result warning... yes
checking if we can turn off gcc unused parameter warning... yes
checking if we can turn off gcc missing field initializers warning... yes
checking if we can turn off gcc invalid function cast warning... no
checking if we can turn on gcc mixed sign comparison warning... yes
checking if we can turn on gcc unreachable code warning... no
checking if we can turn on gcc strict-prototypes warning... no
checking if we can make implicit function declaration an error in gcc... yes
checking whether pthreads are available without options... %
```

Maybe it just takes that long, but I ran both of these over 15 hrs each and so I assume something is going very wrong. I can't find a good SO or other post where someone else is experiencing this problem. Any advice?

```sh
$ uname -a
Linux foo 4.15.0-47-generic #50~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 15 16:06:21 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Doubt it'll be the difference, but I'm running zsh.

Edit: Have tried in bash as well. Placing the export functions in `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.bashrc` with no success. I didn't think these would be the errors since I can call the program just fine and that's all these exports are doing, but I can't figure out what the two commenters are trying to suggest by linking different documentations.

Edit 2:
Running with verbose mode I still see nothing after the Installing line

Comment: I'm not sure what you're getting at. The information is the same in the tutorial I linked. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Considering all 3 links have the same information I'm going to need a little more help than <link to different doc>. Trying the instructions in both (removing `~/.pyenv` each time) I am still getting the same thing. A helpful comment would be an offending line or the key part that I'm missing. I did in fact read the docs before installing (see original post).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems there is some bug. If I hit ctrl-C (once!) it starts building, and successfully works. Will submit bug report.

Comment: Does this bug still exist? This does not work for me.

Comment: Same. Bug still happens for me. No solution found.

Answer (score 15):

Are you sure you have all [build deps](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki#suggested-build-environment) installed on your system? If not run the following:

```bash
sudo apt update; sudo apt install build-essential libssl-dev zlib1g-dev \
libbz2-dev libreadline-dev libsqlite3-dev curl \
libncursesw5-dev xz-utils tk-dev libxml2-dev libxmlsec1-dev libffi-dev liblzma-dev
```

Remove the old version:
`rm -rvf ~/.pyenv/versions/3.7.0`

Then run again:
`pyenv install -v 3.7.0`

Comment: I am sure. I copied that exact line. The solution was ctrl-c (see my answer). I submitted a bug report to them.

Comment: doing these steps helped me out. Thanks WaLid

Comment: Thanks the first line saved my day...

Comment: Thanks. Needed `python3-openssl` for me on Ubuntu 22.04.