# Unable to install Python with pyenv on fresh AWS EC2 instance running Amazon Linux 2023: no module named: _bz2, _curses, _ctypes, readline, _ssl

Tags: python-3.x, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, pyenv

I'm trying to to install Python with pyenv on a fresh AWS EC2 instance running Amazon Linux 2023. I've done these steps:

1. `sudo yum groupinstall "Development Tools"`

```
No match for group package "system-rpm-config"
No match for group package "rcs"
No match for group package "pkgconfig"
```

2. `sudo yum install gcc make patch zlib-devel bzip2 bzip2-devel readline-devel sqlite sqlite-devel openssl11-devel tk-devel libffi-devel xz-devel` (from [pyenv docs](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki#suggested-build-environment))

```
Error: Unable to find a match: openssl11-devel
```

3. `sudo yum install build-essential zlib1g-dev libffi-dev libssl-dev libbz2-dev libreadline-dev libsqlite3-dev liblzma-dev` (from [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60775172/pyenvs-python-is-missing-bzip2-module))

```
Error: Unable to find a match: build-essential zlib1g-dev libffi-dev libssl-dev libbz2-dev libreadline-dev libsqlite3-dev liblzma-dev
```

4. `sudo yum install make build-essential libssl-dev zlib1g-dev libbz2-dev libreadline-dev libsqlite3-dev wget curl llvm libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev xz-utils tk-dev libffi-dev liblzma-dev python-openssl git` (also from [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55696838/pyenv-wont-build-new-python-version-hangs))

```
Error: Unable to find a match: build-essential libssl-dev zlib1g-dev libbz2-dev libreadline-dev libsqlite3-dev libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev xz-utils tk-dev libffi-dev liblzma-dev python-openssl
```

5. following [this guide](https://ggkbase-help.berkeley.edu/how-to/install-pyenv/):

   1. `git clone https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv.git ~/.pyenv`
   2. `echo 'export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"' >> ~/.bash_profile`
   3. `echo 'export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile`
   4. `echo -e 'if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then\n eval "$(pyenv init -)"\nfi' >> ~/.bash_profile`
6. `bash --login` (to start a new shell with the env variables)
7. `pyenv install 3.11.2`

I got these errors (tldr, no module named: _bz2, _curses, _ctypes, readline, _ssl):

```
$ pyenv install 3.11.2
Downloading Python-3.11.2.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.11.2/Python-3.11.2.tar.xz
Installing Python-3.11.2...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ec2-user/.pyenv/versions/3.11.2/lib/python3.11/bz2.py", line 17, in <module>
    from _bz2 import BZ2Compressor, BZ2Decompressor
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_bz2'
WARNING: The Python bz2 extension was not compiled. Missing the bzip2 lib?
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ec2-user/.pyenv/versions/3.11.2/lib/python3.11/curses/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from _curses import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_curses'
WARNING: The Python curses extension was not compiled. Missing the ncurses lib?
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ec2-user/.pyenv/versions/3.11.2/lib/python3.11/ctypes/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'
WARNING: The Python ctypes extension was not compiled. Missing the libffi lib?
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'readline'
WARNING: The Python readline extension was not compiled. Missing the GNU readline lib?
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ec2-user/.pyenv/versions/3.11.2/lib/python3.11/ssl.py", line 100, in <module>
    import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
    ^^^^^^^^^^^
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ssl'
ERROR: The Python ssl extension was not compiled. Missing the OpenSSL lib?

Please consult to the Wiki page to fix the problem.
https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki/Common-build-problems


BUILD FAILED (Amazon Linux 2023 using python-build 2.3.24)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/python-build.20230824022449.134442
Results logged to /tmp/python-build.20230824022449.134442.log

Last 10 log lines:
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/tmp/python-build.20230824022449.134442/Python-3.11.2 ./python -E -m ensurepip \
        $ensurepip --root=/ ; \
fi
Looking in links: /tmp/tmpeswj7w0u
Processing /tmp/tmpeswj7w0u/setuptools-65.5.0-py3-none-any.whl
Processing /tmp/tmpeswj7w0u/pip-22.3.1-py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: setuptools, pip
  WARNING: The scripts pip3 and pip3.11 are installed in '/home/ec2-user/.pyenv/versions/3.11.2/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
Successfully installed pip-22.3.1 setuptools-65.5.0
```

When this completes, `~/.pyenv/versions/` is empty. I'm not sure if that is related to the modules being not found. However, there seems to be a (perhaps incomplete) installation of python 3.11.2 in `/tmp/python-build.20230824022449.134442` (or whatever the date and time is).

Looking inside, I do see the supposed missing modules in `/tmp/python-build.20230824022449.134442/Python-3.11.2/Lib`:

```
bz2.py
curses
ctypes
ssl.py
```

Only `readline` seems missing.

Furthermore, checking for libraries (as per [the wiki](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki/Common-build-problems#1-openssl-is-installed-to-an-uncommon-location)):

```
$ openssl version
OpenSSL 3.0.8 7 Feb 2023 (Library: OpenSSL 3.0.8 7 Feb 2023)
$ which openssl
/usr/bin/openssl
```

I also tried passing the location of OpenSSL headers and libraries explicitly: `CONFIGURE_OPTS="-with-openssl=/etc/pki/tls" pyenv install 3.11.2` (as per [the wiki](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki/Common-build-problems#1-openssl-is-installed-to-an-uncommon-location))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ChatGPT solved this one. What I did was uninstall everything that I previously installed with yum, then install again. I have no fking clue why this works, because the packages all seem to be the same:

```
sudo yum remove gcc make patch zlib-devel bzip2 bzip2-devel readline-devel sqlite sqlite-devel openssl11-devel tk-devel libffi-devel xz-devel bzip2-devel ncurses-devel libffi-devel readline-devel openssl-devel zlib-devel xz-devel
sudo yum clean all
sudo yum install gcc make patch zlib-devel bzip2 bzip2-devel readline-devel sqlite sqlite-devel tk-devel libffi-devel xz-devel bzip2-devel ncurses-devel libffi-devel readline-devel openssl-devel zlib-devel xz-devel
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had both pyenv and openssl@3 installed with homebrew. The solution above with complete removal helped somehow.

1. I removed both openssl and pyenv which were installed with homebrew.
2. Installed pyenv from git as specified in step 5 in this post
3. The command `sudo yum remove gcc make patch zlib-devel bzip2 bzip2-devel readline-devel sqlite sqlite-devel openssl11-devel tk-devel libffi-devel xz-devel bzip2-devel ncurses-devel libffi-devel readline-devel openssl-devel zlib-devel xz-devel` didn't succeed for me, because it tried to delete protected packages as `systemd` and `yum`, but openssl related packages were removed.
4. Installed the packages with `sudo yum install gcc make patch zlib-devel bzip2 bzip2-devel readline-devel sqlite sqlite-devel tk-devel libffi-devel xz-devel bzip2-devel ncurses-devel libffi-devel readline-devel openssl-devel zlib-devel xz-devel`

And finally, it worked for me and I was able to install Python 3.8.9 which I required.
However I am not able to install Python 3.11.2 mentioned in this post, but I think it is because the openssl version installed for me is `OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017`.

**UPDATE**
After all I could not proceed with this version `OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017` because some of the Python libraries did not support it.
Turned out that I had both `openssl` and `openssl11` installed and OpenSSL 1.0.2k took precedence over openssl11.
With the following command `yum list installed | grep openssl` I listed all openssl packages installed with yum and removed all of them and reinstalled just openssl11 related packages.

Final version of all packages is shown below.

```
openssl-libs.x86_64                   1:1.0.2k-24.amzn2.0.12         @amzn2-core
openssl11.x86_64                      1:1.1.1g-12.amzn2.0.20         @amzn2-core
openssl11-devel.x86_64                1:1.1.1g-12.amzn2.0.20         @amzn2-core
openssl11-libs.x86_64                 1:1.1.1g-12.amzn2.0.20         @amzn2-core
openssl11-pkcs11.x86_64               0.4.10-6.amzn2.0.1             @amzn2-core
```

After that I was able to install new versions of Python, including 3.11.2 and the libraries didn`t complain about openssl version.

FYI: if you are using pyenv, which was the case for me, after removing extra openssl and reinstalling openssl11 you need to reinstall Python with pyenv and recreate virtualenv.